# readChar for reading a simple text file as single character

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to use `readChar` to read a simple text file from a project location in Rstudio **(3.6)**. I used

```
fileName <- "/home/sara/myRproject/Text.txt"     # also tried just "Text.txt"
txt <- tolower(readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size))
```

the result is this and couldn't solve it.

> Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(con, "rb") : cannot open file 'Text.txt': No
>   such file or directory

I tried

```
 library(readr)
 text <- readr("/home/sara/myRproject/Text.txt")
```

although I installed the readr package, it shows

> Error in readr("/home/sara/myRproject/Text.txt") :    could not find
>   function "readr"

any step by step help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like multiple problems. First thing you should do is check that the file exists through your terminal `ls /home/sara/myRproject/Text.txt`

Comment: Are you sure the file is present at that location? If yes try `read.table("/home/sara/myRproject/Text.txt")` Also there is no function `readr`, it's a package.

Comment: The next thing might be that you don't have permission to read the file. Also note that `readr` is **not a function** of the [readr package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/1.3.1). Perhaps you were looking for `read_lines`?

Comment: The file exists but it seems it denies to access the file.

Comment: Check the permissions/owner of the file using `ls -l`. The owner must be the same as the user running R

Comment: The both columns show sara for myRproject

Comment: isn't read.table for reading structured text files? I wanna read a simple text file without any special splitters!

Comment: @BlueGirl Are you perhaps after `readLines`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers you mean read.table without readLines can read a simple .txt file?

Comment: @BlueGirl No I mean use `readLines` to read data from a text file line by line. The resulting object is a `character` vector, with as many entries are there are rows in the text file. As you correctly pointed out, `read.table`, `read.delim` etc. are for reading in *table data* from a file (using some form of delimiter).

Comment: @BlueGirl I've added an example below; please take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199494/discussion-between-bluegirl-and-maurits-evers).

Answer (score 0):

Following up from my comment above, here is a minimal & reproducible example of how `readLines` works.

First we create a sample text file consisting of two rows of text.

```
writeLines(c("Line 1", "Line 2"), file("sample.txt"))
```

We can now use `readLines` to read data from any text file line-by-line; the resulting object is a `character` vector with as many entries as there are rows in the text file

```
data <- readLines("sample.txt")
data
#[1] "Line 1" "Line 2"
```